# How to exclude one item from Enum when using zod.nativeEnum

Tags: node.js, typescript, json-schema-validator, zod

I am new to zod schema validator. I have a use case, where I want exclude one item from the list of enum.

I have a colour enum.

```
enum Color {
  Red = 'red',
  Green = 'green',
  Blue = 'blue',
}
```

I want exclude blue from when  I creating the validation schema.

I am using `zod.nativeEnum` ti validate an enum.
How do I exclude one item from `zod.nativeEnum`

I have checked like the following. But that was wrong approch

```
const schema = z.object({
  color: z.nativeEnum(Color).not(Color.Red),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of union & literal:

```
z.union([z.literal(Color.Green), z.literal(Color.Blue)])
```

Link to example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-beaver-rfefvh

Answer (score -1):

You could create an enum with the actual zod schema like so

```
const a = z.nativeEnum( { Red: 'red', Green: 'green', Blue: 'blue' } as const ) //red | green | blue

const omitted = z.omit(a, z.literal(a.values.Red));
```

which allows you to omit a value from that enum and therefore parse with it

Comment: `Property 'omit' does not exist`